# Piping a FileOutputStream to an InputStream without disk i/o

Tags: java, file, streaming, fileoutputstream, disk-io

A third party library casts my SubClassOfOutputStream to a FileOutputStream internally to invoke the getChannel() operation even though they expose an OutputStream interface in their API. This (obviously) causes a ClassCastException.

I need to write to a SubClassOfOutputStream interface. I clearly need to write to a FileOutputStream container, pipe that data to an InputStream, and read bytes from the InputStream in question into my SubClassOfOutputStream instance. Is there a way to do this without disk i/o?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd say your best option is to tell that third party to fix their terrible API, but understanding that is not a realistic option, I think your only other option would be to extend `FileOutputStream` and essentially override the core functionality of it (i.e. - the `write()` methods)

Comment: What operating system are you using? If it's Unix/Linux you can use a named pipe. It looks like a file but does no disk I/O.